# Flutter Main Screen Dimension?

Tags: image, flutter, dart, dimensions

I'm working on an app that shows items when you press the each button a certain amount of times. I want to find a background for the app since plain color isn't looking so good but I  can't find out how big the screen is for a perfect resolution picture. Does anyone know the dimensions of the main screen (excluding the App Bar title)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MediaQuery class

```
var deviceHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
```

Comment: yeah i found it just now in a website called kindacode.com but I'd have thought flutter had a default dimension . thanks